# Jenkins Project-based Matrix Authorization won't grant Admin priveleges for some SAML authenticated users

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, authorization, saml-2.0

I am trying to configure a project-based authorization matrix in Jenkins. All of the users are authenticated through the SAML 2.0 plugin which is functioning as expected. Users are added to an Active Directory group to get access to the server, and then assigned permissions using the matrix. What I would like to do, is have the Authenticated Users group serve as a baseline for what all logged in users are permitted to do, and then grant administrative access to a few Active Directory users who will have Admin privileges. However, only 2 out of the 8 users granted Admin privileges in the Matrix (underlined in blue) are able to see the "Manage Jenkins" button in their portal, while the other 6 users (underlined in red) are unable to see Manage Jenkins. All 8 users are in the same AD group and there are no discernible differences among these 8 users. [auth matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Cqj.png)

Jenkins version is 2.289.1 running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Comment: I've seen a similar issue when there was a mismatch in username casing between granted assignment and the way the user logged in. So for example if SAML returns username as _USER_ but the permission is granted for _user_, these were not matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the that the problem was with Jenkins' config.xml file which Jenkins uses to configure global security. Some users were stored in the format "Firstname, Lastname", while others were stored as their email address. In the Jenkins UI, it will display users as "Firstname, Lastname", but it uses the email address to identify them on the back end. I manually edited the file and replaced all of the user's names with their email addresses. I then ran `sudo systemctl restart jenkins` and allowed me to assign permissions to those users.